# Connecting to and Selecting a Database in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

ok basically i understand that we connect to a database using

```
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
```

and then select the desired database using

```
mysql_select_db("dbname",$conn)
```

so far so good,but what is the difference between selecting and connecting to a database?or am i connecting to the database SERVER and then selecting the desired DB among all the Databases available?thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you connect it first and then you tell the server which Database you want to operate with. Please don't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi extensions instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You are connecting to the server with mysql_connect. Although you can also select the database during mysql connect. But I should note that using the `mysql_` family of functions is deprecated. You shouldn't use these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

---

The difference is that just connecting to the database server will not allow you to create a table or select a table until you select a database to be used for the cause.

With `mysqli` this is also simpler:

```
$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbselect);
if($db->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
```

Comment: thx for cooperation all,i got the point now :)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi), and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

> `mysql_query()` sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Documentation for [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> `mysql_connect()` Opens or reuses a connection to a MySQL server.

Documentation for [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect` connects you to a database **server** not a database, while `mysql_select_db` chooses which database to use on the current mysql connection

MySQL is a server. You're not just "connecting" to a database. There are other layers involved. You first connect to a server, then select a database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connecting means you authenticate your user & password against that instance of MySQL.  You can then access any databases you have permissions to view.

Selecting a database only means when you reference a table without qualifying the database name, it uses that database as a default.  But you can still query any table in any database, you just have to prefix it like, `databasename.tablename`.

PS: As other folks have commented, you should avoid the mysql_* functions, because they have been deprecated recently.  PHP offers two other interfaces to MySQL, which have more features and can be used in an object-oriented fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to the database host first, then select the DB. Otherwise, what's the point of selecting the database if you are not connected to the database host?

And oh, and advice, don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. Use PDO instead.